# date time format issues in C#

Tags: c#, datetime-format

I am attmepting to change a date time format for a search from ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy to just simply yyyy-MM-dd i'm not able to get the syntax right in my conversion so any help would be great.

```
public DateTime CreatedAt
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(this.created_at, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

public DateTime SearchDate
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(CreatedAt.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

searchDate is my issue.

Comment: Are you getting an error, or getting a DateTime object with the wrong values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work:

```
return DateTime.ParseExact(CreatedAt.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

because `CreatedAt.ToString()` is going to create a date time string in the default format (not `yyyy-MM-dd`, which is how you're trying to read it).

But more importantly, why are you trying to convert a date from one string format time to another? If you have the `DateTime` value (CreatedAt, in this case), you can render it however you want (e.g. `CreatedAt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`) There just doesn't seem to be any sense in converting it to a string and parsing parts of it.

And as Bob pointed out, if all you want is the date portion, take `CreatedAt.Date`. Try to think about what your real goal is, though and try to take the shortest route with the fewest conversions (and therefore conversion problems) as possible.

Comment: lol yeah unfortunately some nitpicker downvoted it, even though it was was the most helpful answer.